# Which is better for checking values: isset or = NULL?

Tags: php, html, null, isset

I have a URL that would be like so:

http://mysite.com/index.php?somename=somevalue

I usually check that somename exists by doing:

```
if (isset($_GET['somename'])) {
```

However, I have seen a lot of people do this lately:

```
if ($_GET['somename'] != NULL) {
```

My question is, is either way better than the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike the `null` check,

```
isset($_GET['somename']
```

will not throw an "undefined index" notice, so it's definitely the more preferable of the two.

```
array_key_exists("somename", $_GET);
```

would also be valid.

You may want to combine this with a `null` check however if you want to disallow empty values.

Comment: Footnote: this will not catch the "defined but empty" case that the other option will. It's still the better approach of course.

Comment: @Jon you're right, the `isset()` check won't catch that, but `array_key_exists()` should! I'll add that, thanks.

Comment: No, it won't. Why should it? Please note that I am referring to `?somename=`.

Answer (score 0):

These statements are different.

[isset()](http://php.net/isset) will check if a variable contains a value, whereas the second statement checks if the variable is equal to NULL or not.

In your case, use isset() to determine if $_GET['somename'] exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is usually to do both. The isset checks if the variable exists, while you should also check to see if it is not NULL so that it won't break any later checks.

```
if(isset($_GET['somevalue']) && $_GET['somevalue'] != NULL)
```